# What's the quickest way to write "2nd" "3rd" etc in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, numbering, superscripts

If I want to use abbreviations for second, third and so on in my LaTeX documents, I am currently doing this: `2$^{nd}$` which seems unsatisfactory. Is there a macro I'm missing? I'm sure I could define one myself, and it would be fairly easy. But this looks like something that should already have been covered...

Answer (score 531, accepted):

You should not use math, when it is normal text. Use `\textsuperscript` instead: `2\textsuperscript{nd}`. You can also define a shortcut for this, e.g.

```
\newcommand{\ts}{\textsuperscript}
```

Then you could use `2\ts{nd}` in the text.

**Edit**:
An even nicer solution is to load the package [nth](https://ctan.org/pkg/nth) with the option `super` and use the `\nth` command:

```
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\nth{1}, \nth{2}, \nth{3}, \nth{4}
```

Comment: Is `\nth{<number>}` guaranteed not to be hyphenated?

Comment: @CodeMocker I think that would depend on your hyphenation rules. `nth` doesn't create a box for itself.  I would never expect TeX to hyphenate such, though.

Comment: Options for the package are: ```% In LaTeX: 
%           \usepackage[super,negative]{nth}
% where option [super] gives superscript `th'
% and option [negative] allows ``st, nd, rd'' suffixes on negative numbers.```

Answer (score 137):

I guess the quickest and easiest solution is to simply write "2nd", "3rd", etc.

Superscripts aren't really necessary.

Comment: But where's the fun in that? Any chump can just write "2nd"...

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes life is a little bit boring – there are solutions that are both simple and correct. But as a consolation, bear in mind that most MS Word users will produce 2-superscript-nd *accidentally*, and they have no idea how to disable it.

Comment: Bringhurst (I think) does recommend against using superscript ordinals. But it's nice to be able to `\nth` things automatically, especially in math mode.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Remember that English is not French and does not put `st`, `nd`, `th` into superscripts!

Comment: I  read somewhere  that the superscript ordinals were usually used  by British in the 19th century. I see still here and there. May be this was a foreign influence, but why this changed in the 20th century? To adapt to the preferences of _The Chicago Manual of Style_ or simply because many documents were created with typewriters where it was easier put inline ordinals?. 

In Spanish there are an undisputed reference  for this kind of conventions  (the  Real Academia Española)  but what about English?

Comment: To say "Superscripts aren't really necessary." Sort of misses the point given that we're already writing in LaTeX and so presumably   we care enough about the formatting that the author of the OQ (or anyone else who arrived at this page later) probably already thought through that it would be easier to just write "2nd", "3rd" &c. and decided that they wanted to go through the trouble of having superscripted ordinals. And @tohecz even if a style guide says that a language does things in any particular way, generally (excepting (if you must?) the Académie Française) there is no *correct* answer.

Comment: At first I though: "+100 rep bounty for not answering the question?" However, looking back, this does answer the question. Lesson: Be extra clear when asking on SE. xD

Answer (score 71):

An alternative to `nth` package is **`fmtcount`**.

In this case the command is `\ordinalnum`. By default the ordinal is formatted as superscript, but this is optional, as it is also in `nth`:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount} % equivalent to \usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[level]{fmtcount} % equivalent to \usepackage{nth}
```

But there are some advantages over `nth`:

1. Limited multilingual support (English, French, Spanish, Portuguese, German and Italian). For example, in a Spanish document `\nth{3}` is formatted incorrectly as "3th" but  `\ordinalnum{3}` is rendered almost correctly as "3º" (see *addendum*).
2. Optional gender. For example `\ordinalnum{3}[f]` produces in Spanish the feminine ordinal "3ª" (tercera). There is also a neuter option (`n`). By default the gender is `m` (masculine).
3. Is if possible switch between `raise` and `level` versions  of ordinals in the same document (I can't imagine why, but who know!) with `\fmtcountsetoptions{fmtord=raise}` or `\fmtcountsetoptions{fmtord=level}`
4. For English-only users, obviously (1) and (2) features are useless, but the `ftmcount` package has also many other ordinal commands, as `\ordinal{counter}` or `\ordinalstring{counter}` to print a counter as `section` as an ordinal ("3th") or as textual ordinal ("third") and more.

A third  package, **`engord`**, also print numbers  (`\engordnumber{12}`), counters (`\engord{page}`) and can switch between styles with `\engordraisetrue` or `\engordraisefalse`, but there are not multilingual or gender support.

On the other hand,  for enumerated lists you can use  the **`moreenum`** package with the labels `\raisenth` or `\levelnth`. A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\raisenth* --- ,start=1]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum**: Ordinals in Spanish.

Although often not used, according to the [RAE](http://www.rae.es/) there must be a dot before the superscript, as in any abbreviation ended with a superscript as explained [here](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nypwukqZ6D64M23Yos). Then, the correct ordinal is "3.<sup>o</sup>" (tercero) or "3.<sup>er</sup>" (tercer) but not "3º".

In most cases one can just typing `1.º` or `1.ª` because is Spanish keyboards there are a key for the `º ª \` symbols. However, the problem remain with numbers that can be ended by .<sup>er</sup> (1,3,13,21,23,31,33,etc.). Moreover, in some fonts the  `º` and `ª` symbols are underlined (as in the keyboard), that it is correct in Spanish, but can produce inconsistencies  if one type, for example, `1º,2º,3\textsuperscript{er},4º`. Another problem is that these symbols are only in lower case even using `\MakeUppercase`.

The `babel` package take care of the format of Spanish abbreviations with a superscript suffix, and thus with the `spanish` option one can use `n\sptext{os}` to obtain for example  n.<sup>os</sup> ("numbers" in plural), but moreover provide a shorthands for masculine and feminine ordinals (also in uppercase) using `"` which is not used in LaTeX for quotes. In this way, instead of 1\sptext{er} on can use just `1"er` for example.  In summary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bera}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noindentfirst]{babel}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Lowercase}

1º, 2º, 3º ... 1ª, 2ª, 3ª \dotfill 
Keyboard input, incorrect (no dots). \\
1.º, 2.º, 3.º ... 1.ª, 2.ª, 3.ª 
\dotfill Keyboard input, correct but underlined.\\ 
1\sptext{o}, 2\sptext{o}, 3\sptext{o} ... 
1\sptext{a}, 2\sptext{a}, 3\sptext{a} 
\dotfill With Babel \verb|\sptext{}| command.\\
1"o, 2"o, 3"o ... 1"a 2"a 3"a \dotfill 
With "\ Babel shorthand.\\
1"er 2"o 3"er ... 1"a 2"a 3"a 
\dotfill Apocopate version (primer, tercer, etc.).

\subsubsection*{Upppercase}

\MakeUppercase{1.º, 2.ª, 3.\textsuperscript{er}} ...  
or ... 1.º, 2.ª, 3.\textsuperscript{ER}  
\dotfill (wrong way)\\
1"o 2"a  3"er  $\neq$ \MakeUppercase{1"o 2"a  3"er ... }  
or ...  1"O 2"A  3"ER 
\dotfill (babel way, correct)

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: The `moreenum` package actually just uses `fmtcount` at bottom. (I wrote the package: it's nice to see that a question I asked prompted my to write a package which then became an answer to that question.)

Answer (score 25):

If you are using ConTeXt MkIV, you can even imitate the automatic conversion of MS Word:

```
\usemodule[translate]
\translateinput[2nd][2\high{nd}]
\enableinputtranslation

\starttext
On the 2nd of November \unknown
\stoptext
```

This will translate all `2nd` into `2\high{nd}`.

Comment: Neat. How does this `\translateinput` work? It looks like XeTeX's input mapping but it must occur earlier in the processing.

Comment: I am not 100% sure on how it works. The translate module just registers a "user" filter. Looking at the source, this is how I understand what is happening. The input file is read line by line and first the input translation (encoding regimes and such) is done, then unicode translation (collapsing characters, etc) is done, and finally user translations are done. All this is done in the `openers.textopen` function in  `data-tex.lua` file.

Comment: Is it possible to implement `\translateinput` in LaTeX as well? Might come in handy.

Comment: @marczellm: Since `\translateinput` is based on luatex, it is possible to implement it in LuaLaTeX. But I don't know how easy it will be to translate the ConTeXt code to LaTeX.

Answer (score 21):

If you're after speed when writing, this solution seems to be the quickest to type

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand\nd{\textsuperscript{nd}\xspace}
\newcommand\rd{\textsuperscript{rd}\xspace}
\newcommand\nth{\textsuperscript{th}\xspace} %\th is taken already
\begin{document}
This is the 2\nd of December. Or the 4\nth of July. Or 3\rd place in a race.
\end{document}
```

The `\xspace` command intelligently decides whether there should be a space after the macro or not.

[image: MWE]

Comment: For maintain the space when appropriate you can use the package `xspace`. There are several questions about this package in the corresponding tag.

Comment: Thanks! Edited my answer to include `xspace`.

Comment: I know this answer is quite old, but the question [Drawbacks of `xspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/4918) is maybe worth to have a look at …

Comment: This is my preferred approach as it makes the source code far nicer to read. Who wants to read `\nth{4}`?

Answer (score 7):

Although this question is quite old and has very good answers, I think that maybe there are other people as type-lazy as me, who might appreciate my approach.

Edit: In response to egreg's comments, I wanted to adapt my answer - but the proposed changes would mean that the answer **coincides with Nathanael Farley's answer**, except for the fact that I redefined `\th`. egreg strongly cautions about compatibility issues with actually typing `þ` when redefining `\th` - use at your own risk.

In the interest of completeness, here's my original answer, which distinguished between math mode and text:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{mathtools} % only for \binom

\let\thorn\th % so that thorn-rune \th is not lost
\renewcommand{\th}{%
    \ifmmode% math mode
        ^\mathrm{th}%
    \else%
        \textsuperscript{th}\xspace%
    \fi%
}
% similar commands for \st \nd \rd (which are unoccupied)

\begin{document}
Works both in text (5\th, {\it 2\nd}, {\bf 1\st}, {\sf 3\rd})
and math mode $\displaystyle \left(
5\th, \, \binom{n}{5}\th, \, \sum_{1\st}^{n\th}\right).$
\end{document}
```

[image: th-demo]

This variant will always print upright letters in math mode, instead of adapting to the ambient text style. For a variant that adapts to the ambient style (e.g. italics in theorem environments, use `\textsuperscript` without distinguishing cases, see Nathanael Farley's answer).

I can imagine that someone might consider an exponent hidden in a macro bad form, but then, cases like `n^2\nd` seem far-fetched (and ugly), and I think it's obvious to anyone using LaTeX that this would need to be grouped. For powers, I guess I would prefer the inconsistency of `$n^2$-th` to `$(n^2)\th$` anyway. These kinds of questions seem to be a hotly debated topic, see https://english.stackexchange.com/q/36512.

As a side note, I first tried to build an automatic `\th` which reads the previous character along the lines of [How to find the previously printed character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13326/42225), but managing `\lastbox` and the other primitives turned out to be way above my head. Also, even if this worked, writing `1\th` is really not much quicker than writing `1\st` (using the above), whereas the latter one is much more intuitive.

Comment: Even though it only an example, and my comments are not important, I can't help myself. **(1)** I don't see why is everyone so obsessed with `\xspace`, but it's your personal preference, just be sure that it's frowned upon in some journals. **(2)** You should definitely never need ordinals inside math. **(3)** Don't use `\left(...\right)`, especially not for sums and integrals. Better try `\biggl(...\biggr)`. **(4)** Many copy editors with change `1\st` to `1st` anyways (i.e., no superscript), so why all the fuss ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Short responses in order: **(1)** I have no experience with other solutions that avoid gobbled spaces, but am open to everything that works. **(2)** The math-examples are contrived, but `$(n_1+1)\th$` isn't, and if the brackets are larger than the base size the superscript wouldn't be positioned correctly. Also, it's a compatibility precaution. **(3)** This was purely for bracketing the examples without overloading the MWE, I usually use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` (which are nicely scalable to the desired size).

Comment: Redefining `\th` is a *very* bad idea. Try using UTF-8 encoding and type a `þ` in your document. Of course, simply using `\textsuperscript` in every case is easier. And, finally, no: `th` shouldn't be superscripted.

Comment: Duly noted. I can see the reason to avoid redefining `\th`, but since I have never encountered (let alone used) the rune in question, I felt comfortable in taking this risk. Do you know of any package which uses this internally? You're right about needing no disambiguition if both are to be set in the ambient textstyle, but I like having the possibility of treating them differently (also I wasn't sure what `xspace` would do in math mode). Lastly, superscripting or not comes down to personal preference (various style guides notwithstanding), otherwise there wouldn't be interest in the question.

Comment: @Axel Please, use the `@` mechanism to answer comments, so a notification is issued. Since `\textsuperscript{th}` in math mode does `^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\selectfont #1}}`, it seems useless doing `\mathrm{th}` in that case. So doing `\newcommand{\nth}{\textsuperscript{th}}` does better than the complicated macro you're using. Add `\xspace`, if you prefer; in math mode it does nothing.

Comment: @ all, please excuse my many edits. @egreg, clearly, I still have much to learn. My initial thought was to keep upright letters in math mode, regardless of the ambient font (the reason for \mathrm), but I will admit that I learned about the \ifmmode just recently, so maybe I was more prone to use it than reasonable. I edited my answer to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 3):

### nth package

Example

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{nth}

\begin{document}
    The \verb+nth+ package is my \nth{1} choice when it comes to typsettingh
    nth-stuff. It might also be my \nth{2} and \nth{3} choice.
\end{document}
```

Results in

[image]

### Limitations

- `\nth{$i$}` does not work: [domwass answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4119/5645) does

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most beautiful way (in my opinion) is to input the ordinals as Unicode characters:

```
1ˢᵗ, 2ⁿᵈ, 3ʳᵈ, 4ᵗʰ, $i$ᵗʰ, $n$ᵗʰ
```

renders as

[image: rendered ordinals]

(I believe that requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and a supporting font.)

Comment: That's really interesting. Perhaps the packages above (e.g. nth) actually translate to the Unicode characters? Are they UTF8 compatible? Google is not helpful in this regard (presumably because it treats these phrases as stop words).

Comment: Maybe this requires a specific environment? When I use them in Overleaf like `17ᵗʰ August 2023` it just gives error messages, `LaTeX Error: Unicode character ʰ (U+02B0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply write out the word. 1st = first, 2nd = second, and so on.  Probably better in a formal setting anyway. If this is in a figure or table then any of the above answers sound great, but in a paragraph setting there's no need to get too cute.

Answer (score -1):

Using the `amsmath` package, you could to use the `\text{}` command in the math environment in the following way.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

1$^{\text{st}}$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you think this is better than `1\textsuperscript{st}`? Stylistic considerations aside. By the way, it is essentially the same internally, but much less efficient.