# 1st, 2nd and i-th?

Tags: math-mode, numbering, typography

Assume I wish to refer to the *i*-th object, or the *n*-th function out of some set, where i and n are letters and not numbers (as in "Multiply the `$j$th` row with the `$i$th` column and store the result in the $k$th memory cell, where `$k=i+j$`")

How do you suggest to write it?

`$n$th` is just confusing, `$n$-th` seems weird, and `$n^{\text{th}}$`, which is my current choice, is (pardon me) simply ugly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My preferred form is "$n$-th".

Comment: [After playing with it a little today] 
One option that makes things bearable (at least in my eyes) is `$n^{\text{\tiny th}}$`.

Comment: yours is the method I have always used, too.

Comment: [I think we've had this before...](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/whats-the-quickest-and-easiest-way-to-write-2nd-3rd-etc-in-latex)

Comment: Note that the meaning of the question is where "n" is a letter , rather than a number (e.g. the "i-th" element, the k-th index and the n-th dimension). The other question is specific to numbers (e.g., 1st, 2nd, etc.).

Comment: @RanG. I agree. My preferred forms would be "`multiply row~$j$ with column~$i$`" or "`multiply the $j$-th row with the $k$-th column`". The "th" at exponent is too ambiguous in a math context (and simply ugly in general).

Comment: Yeah, and we are mathematicians: `The $(i+j)$th cell is ...`

Comment: Sorry, but, is this really a question for (La)TeX? To me it seems it is more a question of taste or of the style you need or want to adhere to in general. Even the answers to this question reflect this. How to technically implement the different ways of writing this using (La)TeX has already been discussed [elsewhere on this site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/whats-the-quickest-and-easiest-way-to-write-2nd-3rd-etc-in-latex).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the quickest way to write "2nd" "3rd" etc in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/whats-the-quickest-way-to-write-2nd-3rd-etc-in-latex)

Answer (score 18):

In my experience `$n$th` is most widely used (like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root)). Personally I don't think it's ugly compared to the other two options and I think it's quite readable.

Comment: especially with "i", it looks like a typo of "with" (:

Comment: In spite of this being the most widely used option, I often find myself using `$n$-th`. I'm not sure why exactly, possibly it is because I use `$n$-Bonacci`, `$\beta$-expansion` etc. quite a lot.

Comment: `\(n\)th` may be more correct [if you use LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513/5701).

Comment: @RanG. For i th, would you prefer `$i$-th` or `$i^{th}$` ?

Comment: @CyriacAntony in recent years I've used $i$-th. Not happy about it, but it is (currently) the best option I see.

Answer (score 14):

[AMS Style Guide](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf)
has a strong opinion on this one.

See section 12.7.5.3.

[image]

Comment: Is it just a taste or is there a reason behind it? I think *x*-th is more readable.

Comment: It's meant to be dictatorial. You either follow without questioning or not follow for good reasons.

Comment: If this happens in the statement of a theorem, it is italicized, and $i$th is really looks like ith, with no visual separator between i and th. Which does not look good at all.

Answer (score 11):

$n$th is compatible with the command `\nth{}` which is called-upon by the package `nth`...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{nth}
\begin{document}
\nth{3} is not the same as $\nth{3}$
\end{document}
```

b.t.w. as far as I know this command only work with numbers...

Comment: Yeah, I can't make \nth{$i$} work, sadly.

Comment: How could they not make `\nth` work with `\nth{$n$)`?!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to write it as `$n$ᵗʰ`.

Some more details at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621236/112999.

Answer (score -1):

`$n^{\text{th}}$` is the best if you want to write nth in TEX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I don't want to disturb you, but (1) this was already proposed in the question itself, so as long as you don't accompany it with any relevant sources, it doesn't bring anything new to the topic, and (2) this is the second most ugly solution, after `$n^{\text{\tiny th}}$`, so very far from being the best.

Comment: $n^{\textnormal{th}}$ does not require any package!

Comment: Why is it the best? Why is it better than the other answers?