# Typesetting "nth" in LaTeX

Tags: numbering, superscripts

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>
> - [What's the quickest and easiest way to write “2nd” “3rd” etc in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/whats-the-quickest-and-easiest-way-to-write-2nd-3rd-etc-in-latex)
> - [1st, 2nd and i-th?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10959/11002)

Is there a standard/best practice for typesetting "nth" in LaTeX?  Right now I've got `$n$th`, but that looks a bit weird, with the math-mode *n* right next to the standard-text th.  I've also considered `$n^\text{th}$` (which really seems like too much work).  I'm sure there's some ridiculously simple solution--I just haven't found it yet.  Can you please clue me in?

Comment: `\newcommand{\nth}{$n^\text{th}$}` ?

Comment: This belongs on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Another related question: [1st, 2nd and i-th?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10959/1235)

Answer (score 14):

In mathematical texts it is normal to write `$n$th`. If you want it in superscript (not usual for mathematics AFAIK) you could use `$n^{\text{th}}$`.

Comment: it should be mentioned that it requires `amsmath` for `\text`. Also putting it in `\ensuremath` instead of `$ ... $` would be more fool-proof.

Comment: Depending on fonts, I find that $n^{\text{\tiny th}}$ often looks much better.