# Best and recommended way to write prime on i in $i^{th}$

Tags: math-mode, best-practices, superscripts

I have two `$i^{th}$` and `$i^{\prime th}$` and it is hard to see prime in `$i^{\prime th}$`. I would like to know the opinion of expert LaTeX users about this. I wonder what is the best and recommend way to write `$i^{th}$` and `$i^{\prime th}$`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The superscript "th" seems to have come into use in the Victorian age; then it was dropped and it resurrected when some word processor made it their default. See the nice column on TUGboat by Peter Flynn about this ([TUGboat 26, n. 3, 2005, p.~196](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb26-3/tb84inn.pdf)).

In mathematical writing such a use can be confused with exponents: what does

```
$i^{th}$
```

mean? Is it "*i* raised to the power *th*" or an ordinal?

So I believe it is best to use

```
$i$-th
```

where the hyphen is clearly *not* a minus and so this construction is semantically sound. In case of `the $i'$-th element` one might think whether expanding it into `the element at place~$i'$` is better.

---

It has [been noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550487/134641) that the AMS prefers `$i$th` (but I think their copy editors will make the changes). One can adopt this style, if preferred. Some care should be used, however, because `$i$th` might be quite confusing for the reader. In any case, consistency is the leading word.

Comment: @Emre The hyphen is usually much shorter than the minus sign; moreover the "i" is in italics, while "th" is roman (unless this is in an italics context, where the "expanded" construction might be better).

Comment: @Nagel I've seen both forms. If several instances of the construction are used, defining a macro is in order, so one can change all of them in just one place.

Comment: Also see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91130/134641.

Comment: While opinion-based, it should be noted that the AMS specifically says not to use `$i$-th`, but rather `$i$th`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550487/134641

Comment: @CobyViner So do you think that your opinion warrants a downvote?

Comment: Apologies if you found that rude… I certainly didn't intend it as such! (FWIW, I up-voted a number of your other, related, posts.)

I think that specifically recommending something that is contrary to AMS guidelines, on an opinion-based point, without mentioning that within the answer itself, warranted a down-vote. Just my opinion on this particular matter.

I actually personally prefer your hyphenated version. I do, however, think it important to defer to the AMS in this matter, especially when considering what to use for publication (as I, and I suspect others finding this, are doing).

Comment: @CobyViner OK, I added a paragraph. The policy of the site is to first comment and then possibly downvote. It's not the downvote by itself that's my concern.

Comment: Oh, fair enough—apologies then!

Comment: Although the AMS says to use `$i$th`, that will get you in trouble if it occurs in the statement of a theorem, where the entire text is italic.  I really have no idea how to avoid that.  `$i^{\textup{th}}$` doesn't solve the problem.