# Biblatex - changing pages and publisher/address fields. Inproceedings/incollection

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xpatch

I'm looking to change the order of the fields in `biblatex` for `@inproceedings` and `@incollection` so that the `pages` field comes before the `publisher` and `address` fields. This ordering for book chapters and proceedings is a requirement for various Linguistics journals, and this is an example of how it should look (taken from Isogloss):

> Baker, Mark C. 2008. The macroparameter in a microparametric world.
> In T. Biberauer (ed.), The limits of syntactic variation, 351-373.
> Amsterdam: John Benjamins.

The `booktitle` field would be followed by a comma, and then 'pages'.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{baker2008,
    AUTHOR = "Mark C. Baker",
    BOOKTITLE = "The limits of syntactic variation",
    EDITOR = "T. Biberauer",
    TITLE = "The macroparameter in a microparametric world",
    YEAR = "2008",
    LOCATION = "Amsterdam",
    PAGES = "351--373",
    PUBLISHER = "John Benjamins"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Biblatex on the authoryear style produces this with 'pages' at the end:

[image]

I know that there are various other problems with this output, but I have managed to find fixes for them elsewhere and to include them all here would be too much. I just need the ordering change. I've seen that it can be done through `xpatch`, but these kinds of edits are still beyond me. Would anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I won't have time for an in-depth answer tonight, but some aspects of your desired style seem to be covered by the recent https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629219/35864. Maybe that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's useful and it mentions field ordering in   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles, but not the kind I need and not in the right detail for a beginner like me to apply it here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is not so easy to move around fields in `biblatex` output. See for example the discussion in [How to swap bibliography fields in biblatex-philosophy?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416568/35864). It can be easy when the relevant fields are both called in the same bibmacro, but if that is not the case, a straightforward solution would often need a significant number of lines of code. Sometimes it is possible to cook something up by re- and slightly abusing other bibmacros.

The general idea that we can use here is the same as in [Changing part of a style in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/629219/35864): The `editor`s are moved with `biblatex-ext`'s `innamebeforetitle` option (see e.g. [Biblatex: formatting editor in incollection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433562/35864) and [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/35864)) and the `pages` field can be moved by modifying the `edition` bibmacro to also print `pages` (the `\clearfield{pages}` then deletes the field so that the macro that would normally print the pages does not do so again later on).

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-comp,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addperiod\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{edition}{%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \clearfield{pages}%
  \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \clearfield{eid}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{baker2008,
  AUTHOR    = {Mark C. Baker},
  BOOKTITLE = {The Limits of Syntactic Variation},
  EDITOR    = {T. Biberauer},
  TITLE     = {The Macroparameter in a Microparametric World},
  YEAR      = {2008},
  LOCATION  = {Amsterdam},
  PAGES     = {351--373},
  PUBLISHER = {John Benjamins},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Baker, Mark C. 2008. “The Macroparameter in a Microparametric World”. In: T. Biberauer (ed.), The Limits of Syntactic Variation, 351–373. Amsterdam: John Benjamins.]

Comment: That works beautifully. Thank you so much.