# How to change parameters for \textsuperscript{} in french?

Tags: superscripts

I try to put `\textsuperscript{ère}` with Roman digits everywhere in document but as I understood  the command `\textsuperscript{}` in French makes effect for all symbols except of "è"?

This [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/whats-the-quickest-and-easiest-way-to-write-2nd-3rd-etc-in-latex) didn't help.

Could somebody help to fix it?
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[babel=false]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{german,english,greek,polish,russian}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic,Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

I\textsuperscript{ère}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does good old-fashioned `\textsuperscript{\\`ere}` work?

Comment: @Seamus Unfortunately no. :(

Comment: @filokalos please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) since `\textsuperscript{ère}` and `\textsuperscript{\\`ere}` work for me...

Comment: @Seamus I've put the code.

Comment: Where does `unifrmr` come from? It's not in TeX Live or on CTAN.

Comment: @Joseph Wright No it's a style for geometry and title page.

Comment: @filokalos: Not part of a _minimal_ example, then! See my answer for a minimised file showing the issue.

Comment: @Joseph Wright Ok, thanks. Next time i will do like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be due to the way `xltxtra` redefines the `\textsuperscript` macro: this seems to be thrown by Linux Libertine, as shown by the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

I\textsuperscript{ère}

\end{document}
```

Luckily, it can be fixed using the `no-sscript` option:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

I\textsuperscript{ère}

\end{document}
```

(I've got the font name as `Linux Libertine O` as on my Mac this is the file name needed to get XeTeX to actually find it.)

Comment: If you read the `xltxtra` documentation, this issue is discussed with a different font. What's happening is that `xltxtra` is using real superscripts rather than the usual shrunk-and-shifted characters. However, some superscript glyphs are missing from Linux Libertine, and so only those it has end up superscript!

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % or latin1
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\textsuperscript{ère}
\end{document}
```

Select the right encoding for your system.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm using \usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode} \usepackage{polyglossia} Could you give an advise what should I do in this case?

Comment: @filokalos: as Seamus suggested you before, please provide a minimal example allowing us to reproduce the problem. I did a test with a document with the packages you just mentioned and couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina @Seamus Sorry, I've just corrected the post.