# Problems with xltxtra and footnote

Tags: fonts, fontspec, superscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change parameters for \textsuperscript{} in french?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15035/how-to-change-parameters-for-textsuperscript-in-french)

I use fontspec to load the local fonts (ITC Esprit Std Book). Everything is fine (the only main problem may be, `\/` doesn't work correctly, so I need to add extra space after `\textit` or others when the words end with f).

However, when using footnotes, there is another problem, that is, the footnote number "10" doesn't work correctly. 1 is in superscript char, but 0 is in NORMAL size. But the footnote number "11" is correct. Is there any way to solve this problem?

UPDATE:
It seems this problem does not always happen (it depends on the typeface used). When I changed the typeface to Warnock Pro or Bell MT Std, everything is correct.

Comment: As Joseph suggests, removing `xltxtra` or adding the `no-sscript` option should solve the problem. If it doesn't please add a minimal example.

Comment: Although the solution is the same, I think the questions are sufficiently different to warrant not closing this question?

Comment: Li did the solutions in the comments solve your problem?

Comment: @Alan Yes. It really works. But, the problems are not always happened. (So I updated my question). But, it seems `\/` still doesn't work.