# Possible ways to format a specific century in LaTeX?

Tags: typography, datetime

I'm writing I little bit of history in my report and I wonder which are the possible ways to format a century in LaTeX (e.g XX century) and in typography which is the most used and accepted. This is actually what I'm using:

`XX$^{\circ}$` so I have something like XX° but I don't like it very much, the circle is too low...

Comment: XX°? What’s wrong with “20th century”? XX° looks like an angle with placeholders.

Comment: Is the circ in the superscript really a common notation for centuries? I know only the convention about uppercase roman numerals.

Comment: @GM Ah, I didn’t know that. [Numero ordinale](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numero_ordinale) tells me that in Italian you either use `20°` or `XX` but not `XX°`. Are you sure you want to use XX°?

Comment: The superscript “o” is one of the many French typographic fancies. Nobody else uses it with Roman numerals. Italian for sure doesn't (at least the good books don't).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel sorry "ordinals". Now I see that XX° is not use in practice, I don't know where I learnt it, thanks a lot for the help! Last thing now I've realize that ° is a "o" that is the last letter of the names of ordinal numbers. see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator). :-|

Comment: The practice is outdated, but certainly survives in in French publications.  I have many titles in my `.bib` like "... XIII\textsuperscript{e} siècle...". As an aside: the practice is truly 'medieval', too. Manuscripts (and early printed books) are often heavily abbreviated to save space, so things like , `2ª`, `3º`, `4\textsuperscript{us}`, or `5\textsuperscript{m}` are common, agreeing in gender with some other (implied) word in the nominative, accusative, or ablative case.  Unless, you are required to do so, I suggest avoiding the practice, and also things like `20\textsuperscript{th}`.

Comment: @egreg I have never seen it even in French, except as an abbreviation for latin words (primo, secundo, tertio, etc.)., but never for centuries – at leas not in any decent book.

Comment: @ienissei I wasn't referring specifically to centuries; I've seen Roman numbers with the superscript in French and I believe it's mandatory in some situations.

Comment: If you would like more control on the appearance (height, size) of text superscripts, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/superscript-outside-math-mode/140703#140703

Comment: @egreg Roman numerals come with a superscript "o" for primo, secundo, etc. so they could appear anywhere in headings or enumerations. In typographically correct books, centuries are set with a superscript "e" (and capital roman numerals). But generally, yes, superscripts are mandatory in French for any ordinal number (except only good editors use the proper characters).

Comment: Actually, this is the accepted practice in Polish, as in "XX w." which is the standard abbreviation of "XX wiek".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ordinal indicators º/`º`  and ª/`ª` can be typeset with `\textsuperscript{o}` and `\textsuperscript{a}` respectively.

While the `french` option of `babel` actually uses a `\realsuperscript` macro that aligns the superscripts a little bit lower, the `italian` option doesn’t have this.

An alternative offers the input of Unicode characters with the `utf8` option of the `inputenc` package (of course, you need to have your documents UTF-8 encoded).

The `textcomp` packages defines `\textordmasculine` and `\textordfeminine` which do look a little different and are underlined.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\let\up\textsuperscript
\begin{document}
20\up{o} secolo\par 20º secolo \par
20\up{a} Vespa\par 20ª Vespa
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I see no problem with using XX as 20th century... but if you want to change it a little bit you should only change its style, for example:

```
\emph{XX} Century
\textsl{XX} Century
\textbf{XX} Century
\texttt{XX} Century
\textsc{XX} Century
```

Which would look something like this:

[image]

Of course, feel free to *combine* (keeping of course esthetics  and reason on sight) any of the options below.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with @Mario S. E.' s answer (Nothing personal :-), which proposses to use `\text<sth>` macros to format the century numbers. I would nearly never use them in the document body, especially when they are used for mark up, as it is the case here. Even mixing them isn't a good idea either. You could instead do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\centuryname{century}
\let\up\textsuperscript
\let\markcent\textsc
  \newcommand*{\century}[1]
  {\markcent{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral #1\relax}}\up{o} \centuryname}

\begin{document}
\century{20}
\end{document}
```

(with credits to @Qrrbrbirlbel' s answer).

**Edit:** Regarding the position of the 'o' etc., try another definition for `\up`. Replace `\let\up\textsuperscript` with

```
\def\up#1{%
\edef\tmp{\the\fontdimen14\textfont2}%
\fontdimen14\textfont2=5.5pt%
\textsuperscript{#1}%
\fontdimen14\textfont2=\tmp%
}
```

Finally, you could code a little more customizability by

```
\newcommand*{\up}[2][5.5pt]{%
\edef\tmp{\the\fontdimen14\textfont2}%
\fontdimen14\textfont2=#1%
\textsuperscript{#2}%
\fontdimen14\textfont2=\tmp%
}
```

which then could be used like `\up[height correction]{superscript}`.

Comment: +1 for the separation between content and format. But it would be better to have it in LaTeX commands instead of TeX primitives (although `\romannumeral` is unavoidable): `\newcommand{\century}[1]{\textsc{\romannumeral #1}\textsuperscript{o}~\centuryname}`.

Comment: Writing 'Jahrhundert' works in German, but not 'Century' in English.  We are living in the twenty-first century, not the twenty-first Century.  (I still prefer spelling it out, however....)

Comment: I do like your answer :)  Actually ---personally--- I would just type directly XX century, with no problem at all.

Comment: @MarioS.E.: Then, at least I would use it like: `\markcent{XX}` century (in lower case; you're right @jon!). With this you still keep a consistent format which is changable at any time.

Comment: @Ruben Not to start a fight or anything :), but what's the deal with using for example `\emph{XX} century`?  You can always got `CTRL+H` and simply change all the `\emph{XX}` for `XX`

Comment: @MarioS.E. sure it's no big deal but becomes more and more tedious the more different centuries you have (XX, XIV, XVI ...). Then you may have a hard time not to forget one when changing the layout. IMHO good LaTeX practice _always_ should be to _strictly_ separate markup from layout...

Comment: It has to do with a canonic guideline of TeX coding: separation of content and format. Moreover: If you code your text in a notepad with does not support a search-and-replace function, you have a problem. And if you maybe used several commands, you have to remember which one they were. Hence, there is a probability that you will miss some and this is a problem too.

Comment: You both @cgnieder and Ruben have an excellent point.  I'll keep that in mind. Thanks :)