# How do you format a Dates Contraction in LaTex?

Tags: fonts, syntax

I'm writing a paper and I need to include a date, for example `20th January 2011`.

How can I make the Contraction smaller and position it correctly as an ascender/superscript?

[image: example]

Comment: See [Superscript outside math mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47324/5764).

Comment: Thanks Werner. Your solution on that question worked perfectly.

Comment: Would be a good job for the »[nth](http://ctan.org/pkg/nth)« package.