# What is a good way to write exponentials within paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs

I want write a paragraph that has an exponential term in it, like `the complexity is on the order of 10^5'.

This exponential changes the spacing between the lines of the paragraph. I have seen in some textbooks that they make the size of the base smaller so that it blends in the paragraph.

I wanted to ask what is a good way to have exponential terms in a paragraph in LaTeX without changing the format of the paragraph.

The code can be found here -- the required style file spconf is here (http://www.ieee.ca/ccece09/templates/spconf.sty):

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{article}
\usepackage{spconf}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{subdepth}

\begin{document}

\ninept

\title{Example code} 
\name{}
\address{}

\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque egestas
posuere eros at feugiat. Morbi adipiscing tempus arcu, et suscipit purus laoreet
eget. Maecenas pulvinar faucibus leo eget feugiat. Pellentesque aliquet placerat
dui id mollis. Etiam convallis tristique tortor, in tempus leo $10^5$ accumsan
sed. Pellentesque interdum metus eu orci convallis mattis. Nunc accumsan
lobortis mi vitae blandit. Integer rhoncus eros dui, ut vestibulum justo ornare
ut. Suspendisse id enim lacus. Proin non blandit neque. Donec lacinia, ipsum
quis vestibulum pulvinar, metus nibh laoreet ante, in semper ligula mi porttitor
purus. Curabitur tempus, leo 10\textsuperscript{5} et cursus congue, tellus
felis ornare neque, ac sagittis tortor leo sit amet sapien. Praesent diam felis,
rhoncus ut eros eget, placerat scelerisque tellus. Quisque elementum turpis non
massa lacinia, condimentum malesuada nisl tincidunt.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could write "the order of 1e5". `:-)`

Comment: Please always post a _complete_ document that shows the problem. With the default fonts and settings an  exponent fits in the linespacing \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
$10^5$
abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc 
abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc 


\end{document}

Comment: The exponent you get is way too high, which doesn't happen when `mathptmx` or `newtx`, see [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9D5qS.png) How are you inputting that number?

Comment: My answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/superscript-outside-math-mode/140703#140703 might be helpful, since it allows control of the height/size of the superscript.

Comment: The superscript `5` in your screenshot looks both *too small* and *too high*. Using some TeX jargon, it looks like the `5` was typeset in `scriptscriptstyle` rather than in `scriptstyle`, say, via `$10^{{}^5}$` instead of via `$10^5$`. Please state the code that gave rise to this screenshot.

Comment: When I studied the code in light of your feedback I saw that this behavior is due to using the `subdepth' package. I am using this package due to many subscripts and superscripts in the text.

Comment: @dagcilibili - Please post an MWE (minimum working example) that generates the output you're looking to fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load the `subdepth` package with the `low-sup` option, if you really want to load it.

You should also do `\usepackage{mathptmx}` or, better,

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

and, definitely, type the number as `$10^{5}$`. In the example I left the construction `10\textsuperscript{5}` just to show that the output in correct nonetheless.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{spconf}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}

\begin{document}

\ninept

\title{Example code} 
\name{}
\address{}

\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque egestas
posuere eros at feugiat. Morbi adipiscing tempus arcu, et suscipit purus laoreet
eget. Maecenas pulvinar faucibus leo eget feugiat. Pellentesque aliquet placerat
dui id mollis. Etiam convallis tristique tortor, in tempus leo $10^5$ accumsan
sed. Pellentesque interdum metus eu orci convallis mattis. Nunc accumsan
lobortis mi vitae blandit. Integer rhoncus eros dui, ut vestibulum justo ornare
ut. Suspendisse id enim lacus. Proin non blandit neque. Donec lacinia, ipsum
quis vestibulum pulvinar, metus nibh laoreet ante, in semper ligula mi porttitor
purus. Curabitur tempus, leo 10\textsuperscript{5} et cursus congue, tellus
felis ornare neque, ac sagittis tortor leo sit amet sapien. Praesent diam felis,
rhoncus ut eros eget, placerat scelerisque tellus. Quisque elementum turpis non
massa lacinia, condimentum malesuada nisl tincidunt.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I find the typesetting `spconf` does is too tight with `\ninept`, as it sets a baseline skip of slightly less than 10.5pt rather than the 11pt that `\small` would choose.

Add `\linespread{1}\selectfont` if you want a “better” interline spacing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solves the problem with very nice extra knowledge!