# Superscript problems when using bibtex

Tags: bibtex, superscripts

How do i use superscript without using math mode?

I want to write `2 m^{2}` (2 squaremeters).

When i use the command `m^{2}` I get the following error: `"Command \ae invalid in mode"`

I'm writing my thesis in danish, and have a lot of danish references. Writing the danish letter Æ is only possible using the `\ae` command in citations.

```
\documentclass[.....]{memoir}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/superscript-outside-math-mode perhaps? But you have shown us nothing about your bibliography related content. There might be other/better(?) solutions than `\textsuperscript`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Perfect! \textsuperscript{ ... } helped me!

Comment: You should use `siunitx` to get the proper spacing, 2 m^2 (in text mode) will not have the proper spacing between the value and the unit.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command `\textsuperscript{ ... }` solved the problem.