# Controlling vertical placement of letters

Tags: fonts, positioning

I would like to be able to control the vertical placement of letters in a word without affecting the horizontal spacing or the size of the letters, just their vertical position.

I have tried using pstricks and just putting the individual letters at the height that I want, but now I run into problems with horizontal spacing.

```
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-1,-1)(1,1)
  \rput[Bl](-0.4,0.4){\huge p}
  \rput[Bl](0.05,0.2){\huge a}
\end{pspicture} \\

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-1,-1)(1,1)
  \rput[Bl](-0.4,0.4){\huge m}
  \rput[Bl](0.05,0.2){\huge a}
\end{pspicture} \\ 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=grid](-1,-1)(1,1)
  \rput[Bl](-0.4,0.4){\huge t}
  \rput[Bl](0.05,0.2){\huge a}
\end{pspicture} \\
```

In the examples above, "ba" looks good enough, but then "ma" overlaps because of the thickness of m, and "ta" looks too far apart because of the thinness of t.

I'm looking for anyway to accomplish this. Can I control vertical placement in regular text mode, maybe math mode? In pstricks, can I somehow calculate the horizontal placement to deal with the different letter widths? (I will also want to do more than 2 letters.)

[image: Here's what it looks like]

Comment: What about `m\raisebox{1ex}{m}`?

Comment: My answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/superscript-outside-math-mode/140703#140703 could help.

Comment: @Sigur Yes! I am pretty sure that will do the trick. There may be a future complication, but this seems to be the best so far! Thanks for such a quick response. (I feel a little silly now that it was that easy, but google failed me on this one.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I will look at this in a bit more depth tonight. But thank you for the reference!