# How do I input the symbol for Solar Mass?

Tags: symbols, physics

I need to put stellar mass data in units of Solar Mass, and I tried the `M_{\odot}`, but the console shows:

```
! missing $ inserted error.
```

I don't know what is wrong. Please help me out

Comment: You can't use subscripts in text mode.  Either use $M_\odot$ or M\textsubscript{$\odot$}.

Comment: I suggest reading https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics ... worth the time

Comment: It was very silly of me to miss that. Thanks!

Comment: Or use the `wasysym` package and `\astrosun`

Comment: @Rmano NOOOO!  Not the wikibook.  It's crap.  Read [LaTeX and Friends](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642238154) instead!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: Why the vote to reopen?

Comment: @Troy the question is clearly about TeX (not off-topic), it is clear enough that although there's no MWE the problem can be recognised (not unclear), and even **has an upvoted answer** - why close as off-topic in the first place?  Solved in comments is not a valid close reason, something like problem was just a typo which was identified in the comments can be but that doesn't strike me as the case here.  Perhaps this should be closed as a dupe but that's a whole different thing.

Comment: @Hansatanu Roy: Please consider accepting my answer if it satisfies you.

Comment: Related: [Superscript outside math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47324/5764)

Answer (score 23):

TeX complains with `missing $ inserted` because of the underscore. `_` is a special character dedicated for subscripts, which require math mode.

My first example is all math mode, the second one is typesetting the M in upright text mode, the third uses text mode for the subscript. Choose for yourself whether the solar mass should be typeset in math italic—as a variable—or upright—as having a defined meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\(M_\odot\)
or
\(\textup{M}_\odot\)
or
M\textsubscript{\(\odot\)}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is a bit old but I must comment on one point: denoting `_` as *active character* is misleading. TeX reserves this name to chars with category code 13. The underscore is a *subscript* character (category code 8). In your answer I would rather use "special character" to avoid issues.

Answer (score 4):

In Unicode, the symbol you want is U+2609, and can be loaded from any font that contains it using `fontspec`.  Here is an example using DejaVu Sans, and the output with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Sans}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\newcommand\astrosun{{\symbolfont\symbol{"2609}}}
\newcommand\solarmass{\ensuremath{\mathrm{M}_{\textnormal{\astrosun}}}}

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbering.

\begin{document}
Solar mass is denoted {\solarmass}.
\end{document}
```

[image: DejaVu Sans sample]