# Number within Circle as an Exponent on Text

Tags: superscripts

I need to put a number within a circle on top of a text (i.e., as an exponent). How to go about it?

I am doing something like

```
\raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {8}}}
```

but unable to make it as an exponent of some word.

Comment: Tikz? PSTricks? Picture mode? Christmas tree balls?  Magic? Depends ...

Comment: I am doing something like, \raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {8}}}, but unable to make it as an exponent of some word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mysup}[1]{\textsuperscript{\raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.8pt}{#1}}}}}

\begin{document}
     Blah blah\mysup{8} blah
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think you took the `\raisebox` technique from [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) and your question is a duplicate of [Superscript outside math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/superscript-outside-math-mode).

Comment: Thanks CarLaTeX for the help. The issue got resolved.

Comment: @engqureshi You're welcome, and don't forgot a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) next time. Happy Xmas!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mysup[2]{$\stackrel{\textcircled{\footnotesize#2}}{\mbox{#1}}$}

\begin{document}
    Blah \mysup{blah}{8} blah\mysup{}{8}
\end{document}
```

[image]