# Superscript in misc bibtex title

Tags: bibliographies

```
@misc{rotgdo30j2012agdo31j2012,
    author = {{Central Electricity Regulatory Commission}},
    title = {{Report on the grid disturbance on {30^{th}} July 2012 and grid disturbance on {31^{st}} July 2012}},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.cercind.gov.in/2012/orders/Final_Report_Grid_Disturbance.pdf}},
    year = {2012},
    month = {August}
}
```

I am unable to get the superscripts "30^{th}" and "31^{st}" in my bibliography. How can this be achieved?

I am using

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

Comment: This should work like normal superscripts outside math mode, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47324/35864

Comment: Your issue is in no way related to bibtex, biblatex, or the `ieeetr` bibliography style. Instead, it's related to the use of `^` in text mode (as opposed to math mode). Are you familiar with the `\textsuperscript` macro?

Comment: BTW, isn't it more standard to write it as 30th nowadays. Without the raised th