# \textit{x_{min}} have error?

Tags: symbols

I want to write:

[image]

and give error:
[image]

When I put

```
\textit${x_{min}}$
```

It also error

Comment: Do you want to use it in the text or inside of a mathematical formula? `$x_{min}$` should work for the latter

Comment: @leandriis, I want to use in text and also make it `italic`. so I added in \textit{x_{min}}

Comment: You should rather use `$x_{\min}$` instead of what you're currently doing. At best, you're need `\textit{x\textsubscript{min}}`.

Comment: @aan: `_` for a subscript only works in math mode. Hence the error message when you use it in text mode.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): [Superscript outside math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47324/134144)

Comment: Why do you want `x_{min}` to be italic?  The usual reason would be "because it's math", but that is the opposite of "use it in text".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\textit(x_{min}}` is an error as the content of `\textit` is text mode so can not have `_`

`\textit$x_{min}$` is  `\textit{$}x_{min}$` with a lone `$` as argument to `\textit`

the usual markup would be `$x_{\min}$`  or if you really do want min in italics `$x_{\mathit{min}}$`

If it is not mathematics then `\textit{x\textsubscript{min}}` is another possibility.

Comment: You probably mean `\textit{x\textsubscript{min}}` :-)

Comment: @Zarko up, down, what's the difference:-)

Comment: position of `min` :-) :-), however in principle there is no difference, so you are right :-)

Comment: Maybe a less elegant suggestion but what if you put \ in front of _ given that you want to have it in text?

Comment: @Dario I'm assuming the questioner wants x with a subscript "min" not just text with a literal underscore `x_min` ???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. My bad. You are right. I just focused on the fact that using underscore in text produces an error.