# How to have subfont and without italic?

Tags: italic

How to avoid italic for "th"?

```
in the early 20$^{th}$ century
```

[image]

How to avoid italic font and just "20th"?

Comment: `20$^{\mathrm{th}}$`.  If you use `\textrm`, the `th` will not be shrunk in size (unless you load `amsmath`), but it will still be upright

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I suggest to use this link :-) where there is also your answer :-)))) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47324/superscript-outside-math-mode

Comment: @Sebastiano I was going to suggest that too, but you beat me to it.  Touche!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ahahahah....and I have a slow web connection ahahah.

Comment: The simplest way is to write “20th century” instead of using the Victorian age method that some people at Microsoft deemed nice and made it the default for Word. With the effect that users came to think it is the right method: it isn't.