# Macro to generate ordinal words from numbers?

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

Is there a macro available that will turn "1" into "first", "2" into "second", etc.  Let's call this macro "`wordth`".  Then, for example, if item number 2 in an `enumerate` environment is labeled by `\label{item:blah}`, I could write something like

```
The \wordth{\ref{item:blah}} item is problematic.
```

which would be formatted as "The second item is problematic."

(Bonus points for other languages, but I only need it for English.)

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/whats-the-quickest-way-to-write-2nd-3rd-etc-in-latex) points to the [nth](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/nth.html) package for turning "1" into "1st", etc.  The [engord](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/engord.html) package also does this.  Neither appears to provide fully spelled out English ordinals.  In many situations only full words for ordinals, not their abbreviations, are appropriate.

This is probably a FAQ, but it's one of those things that's difficult to search.  Feel free to point to a dupe question and close.

Comment: The `fmtcount` package should help.

Comment: For the bonus points, `fmtcount` also supports French, German, Spanish, Portuguese (although there's a bug that'll be fixed in the next release), German (likewise) and, by sneakily loading `itnumpar` and ensuring it works with the `fmtcount` commands, Italian.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) (for writing the ordinal form of a *counter*) and [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) for extracting the number associated with a reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount, fmtcount}

\newcommand*{\wordth}[1]{% \wordth{<reference>}
  \ordinalstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item\label{enum:first} First item.
  \item\label{enum:second} Second item.
  \item Last item.
\end{enumerate}

See the \wordth{enum:second} item above, or item number~\ref{enum:first}.

\end{document}
```

Since you are using the `\label`-`\ref` system, you need to compile at least twice on the first go in order to work with settled references.

Note that `\wordth{<reference>}` requires a reference to some label. If you wish to reference hierarchical numbering schemes (like a subsection that is numbered `1.1`) you're going to run into trouble. However, one could use [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)'s magic to circumvent this. It would require a little more muscle to work, including a possible interface change.

Comment: The only objective I have is the usage of the superscript.

Comment: @tohecz That's easily fixed with the `level` package option.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Yes I know. I only now realized that I forgot to start by "+1" :)

Comment: It looks like `\ordinalstringnum` rather than `\ordinalnum` is the macro that produces the effect I wanted.  I submitted an edit that makes that substitution.  With that change, it's perfect.  Thanks, especially for the use of `\refcount`; without that, I would have just gone in circles with fmtcount.

Comment: I want to accept this answer, but it's still not quite correct two days after the answer was posted.  There was a typo or minor oversight in the original answer.  When `\ordinalstringnum` is substituted for `\ordinalnum`, it will be correct, I believe.  Werner, you may be busy with the real world--the delay is no problem--but I thought I'd post a reminder comment.  Thanks.  (If someone else with edit-acceptance power wants to verify that my edit is correct and accept it, that would solve the issue, too.)

Comment: @Mars: I've updated the answer to your specifications.

Answer (score 7):

If this is the only way you intend to reference the item, you could incorporate `\ordinalstring` into `\theenumi`. (I'm assuming this is just for use in an `enumerate` environment.) For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\ordinalstring{enumi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item\label{item:blah} Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

The \ref{item:blah} item is problematic.

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, scoping the change so it only affects this particular `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\ordinalstring{enumi}}
\item First item.
\item\label{item:blah} Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

The \ref{item:blah} item is problematic.

\end{document}
```

Both produce:

[image: Image of result]

Comment: Thanks.  Nice idea.  In my case, I want to be able to do both.  Sometimes "blahblah number 2" is natural in a sentence, and sometimes "second" is.

Comment: @Mars In which case Werner's answer is best :-)

Comment: Yes, but it's good to have alternative solutions for different cases.