# Maintain hyperref using refcount and fmtcount

Tags: hyperref, fmtcount, refcount

I am using a combination of `refcount` and `fmtcount` to allow chapter references to produce a string (based on the solution to [Macro to generate ordinal words from numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184032/macro-to-generate-ordinal-words-from-numbers)). However, I have found that when using `hyperref` such references lose their link.

A minimal working example is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\chapterref}[1]{%
    \Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The First Chapter}\label{cha:first}
Hello, this is a chapter.

\chapter{The Second Chapter}\label{cha:second}
In Chapter~\chapterref{cha:first} we did very little indeed. In Chapter~\ref{cha:second} we have done a little more.

\end{document}
```

Which produces this for the second chapter:

[image: MWE ouput]

The reference produced with the `\chapterref` command has no link whereas the reference produced with the conventional `\ref` command does.

Any suggestions as to how to incorporate `hyperref`?

Comment: It seems that `refcount` does not automatically do a link

Answer (score 5):

Just wrap `\hyperref` around the reference:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\chapterref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\Numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The First Chapter}\label{cha:first}
Hello, this is a chapter.

\chapter{The Second Chapter}\label{cha:second}

In Chapter~\chapterref{cha:first} we did very little indeed.
In Chapter~\ref{cha:second} we have done a little more.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TomBrien: Perhaps you did not have `hyperref` **after** the other packages ;-)

Comment: Actually no I went through the undo history, it was fine except the braces for `hyperref` were misplaced. Oh well live and learn