# How do I use memoir ordinal* commands with references?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir

I'd like to use `memoir`'s `\ordinaltoname` to refer to a specific item in an enumerated block. The item is marked with a label command. The naive code fails to compile, apparently because the label is undefined on the first pass and `\ordinaltoname` doesn't know what to do. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\begin{enumerate}
 \item{}\label{por:existence}First point;
 \item{}\label{por:defn}Second point;
 \item{}\label{por:associativity}Third point.
\end{enumerate}

\ordinaltoname{\ref{por:existence}}

\backmatter


\end{document}
```

Upon compiling,

```
[78] Yeah? pdflatex mwe
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2018/04/04 v3.7g configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifetex/ifetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/plain/ifetex/ifetex.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo))
No file mwe.aux.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.23 \ordinaltoname{\ref{por:existence}}

?
```

What is the correct way to convert a label reference to a number usable in a command like ordinal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar in nature to [Macro to generate ordinal words from numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184032/5764). You can get by using with [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount)'s `\getrefnumber`, which is expandable:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{por:existence}
    First point;
  \item \label{por:defn}
    Second point;
  \item \label{por:associativity}
    Third point.
\end{enumerate}

This reference points to the \ordinaltoname{\getrefnumber{por:existence}} element.

\end{document}
```