# Book edition string for APA style of biblatex in Spanish

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, spanish

I am using the APA style of `biblatex` for a document written in Spanish. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book,
    author = {Author Name}, 
    year = {2013},
    title = {Title},
    edition = {3},
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}

\begin{document}
\autocite{book}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The MWE produces the following output in the list of references:

> Name, A. (2013). Title (3.<sup>a</sup> ed.). City: Publisher.

The dot between the number '3' and the superscript 'a' does not make any sense to me and I would like to remove it.

I can change the bib file to get my desired output, with something like this:

`edition = {3\textsuperscript{a} ed\adddot},`

This produces an output like:

> Name, A. (2013). Title (3<sup>a</sup> ed.). City: Publisher.

Is there a way to reach this without changing my bib file?

Comment: Do not make any sense for you, but is the correct  way. From  the Diccionario panhispánico de dudas: "En las abreviaturas que llevan letras voladas, el punto se escribe delante de estas". Moreover, babel take care of this to avoid this common mistake. Please see  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91130/11604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex`'s Spanish language module uses [`babel-spanish`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel-spanish)'s `\sptext` command to typeset the ordinal indicator. According to http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=ordinales&lema=ordinales it is a rule in Spanish that the abbreviation dot should be included alongside the superscripted ordinal indicator.

The way to get rid of the dot in all abbreviations typeset with superscripted endings would be to redefine `\sptext`. The following MWE locally redefines `\sptext` for `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \savecommand\sptext
  \renewcommand*{\sptext}{\textsuperscript}}

\UndefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \restorecommand\sptext}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book,
  author    = {Author Name}, 
  year      = {2013},
  title     = {Title},
  edition   = {3},
  address   = {City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{book}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 3^a without dot]

Note that current versions of `biblatex` and `biblatex-apa` don't need the `\DeclareLanguageMapping` any more, so I dropped it.

---

If this should be only about the edition and all other ordinals and abbreviations should not be touched you could try only

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \def\mkbibordedition#1{\stripzeros{#1}\textsuperscript{a}}}
```

---

If you want to influence all ordinal numbers, you would use

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibmascord#1{\stripzeros{#1}\textsuperscript{o}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibfemord#1{\stripzeros{#1}\textsuperscript{a}}}
```

Comment: +1, but Is not a common practice, is a a rule that is commonly ignored.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the comment. I don't speak Spanish and wasn't too sure about the status of the linked page (which I found through Wikipedia) especially about its prescriptive authority. I reworded the introductory paragraph to emphasise that this is a rule and not just common practice.