# Custom order enumeration in Spanish

Tags: lists, enumerate

I would like to customise the enumerate environment so I can enumerate an order. As you see in the MWE I have only achived to put a number and a customization in this way:

- Etapa 1
- Etapa 2
- ...

However, I would like to write something like:

- 1ª Etapa
- 2ª Etapa
- ...

Following the MWE, I understand that I have to swap 'Etapa' and '\arabic*' but I don't know how to put the superscript indicating an order, less to write that superscript in Spanish.

```
\begin{document}

% -------------------
% Itemise and Enumerate
% -------------------
\usepackage{enumerate,enumitem}

% -------------------
% Itemise and Enumerate
% -------------------
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Una aproximación normativa en Economía Pública como un conjunto de reglas y principios con los que lograr una gestión eficiente de la actividad financiera del Sector Público, es decir, dados unos fines y objetivos, cuáles son las medidas óptimas para alcanzarlos. Dentro de ese enfoque nos encontraremos con una serie de etapas básicas:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=Etapa \arabic*:, align=left, leftmargin=*]
        \item Qué fines u objetivos se pretenden alcanzar con el Sector Público. Por ejemplo, si queremos un medio ambiente limpio, eliminando la contaminación de los ríos
        \item Ver los medios para alcanzar los objetivos sus efectos en cada uno de los instrumentos. A saber, regular el vertido de residuos, sancionar o premiar, limpiezas de cauces, invertir en tecnologías no contaminantes
        \item Elegir el medio óptimo para conseguir los objetivos. Dentro del anteriores ejemplos se analizan las consecuencias de cada uno de los instrumentos y se elige el conjunto más adecuado
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Nos encontramos ante un enfoque positivo cuando lo que hacemos es describir como se toman las decisiones dentro del Sector Público, que agentes son los que participan, señalar que efectos tiene sobre la economía y finalmente predecir que decisiones tomará en el futuro el Sector Público.
    
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably `\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*\textsuperscript{a} Etapa:, align=left, leftmargin=*]` helps?

Comment: It does!!! many thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Alternatively, you could also be interested in using `\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*"a Etapa:, align=left, leftmargin=*]` (Needs `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`).

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91130/134144

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\FCloadlang{spanish}
\newcommand{\myOrdstring}[1]{\protect\Ordinalstring{#1}[f]}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Una aproximación normativa en Economía Pública como un conjunto de reglas y principios con los que lograr una gestión eficiente de la actividad financiera del Sector Público, es decir, dados unos fines y objetivos, cuáles son las medidas óptimas para alcanzarlos. Dentro de ese enfoque nos encontraremos con una serie de etapas básicas:
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\myOrdstring{enumii} Etapa:, align=left, leftmargin=!]
        \item Qué fines u objetivos se pretenden alcanzar con el Sector Público. Por ejemplo, si queremos un medio ambiente limpio, eliminando la contaminación de los ríos
        \item Ver los medios para alcanzar los objetivos sus efectos en cada uno de los instrumentos. A saber, regular el vertido de residuos, sancionar o premiar, limpiezas de cauces, invertir en tecnologías no contaminantes
        \item Elegir el medio óptimo para conseguir los objetivos. Dentro del anteriores ejemplos se analizan las consecuencias de cada uno de los instrumentos y se elige el conjunto más adecuado
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Nos encontramos ante un enfoque positivo cuando lo que hacemos es describir como se toman las decisiones dentro del Sector Público, que agentes son los que participan, señalar que efectos tiene sobre la economía y finalmente predecir que decisiones tomará en el futuro el Sector Público.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I need but changing the actual wording by ordinal numbers instead

Comment: It was only a suggestion – using ordinal strings instead of the abbreviation. With the abbreviation, @Leandriis' comment gives the way do do it.